# How to prevent iOS Voiceover from reading flyout menu items when menu isn't showing

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, voiceover

I'm using Xamarin Forms 5 to build an app that uses the stock flyout menu. When Voiceover is activated, it reads the menu items from the flyout menu when the menu is not showing and the menu items are not selectable. When the menu is showing, Voiceover behaves as expected. How do I prevent VO from "reading" the menu when it isn't in view? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I should be able to set AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree to "true" or "false" to toggle "visibility" to Voiceover, but it doesn't work and appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since Forms 4.4.0, Voiceover does not skip layout and read **all children** in declaration order, setting `AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "false"` also does not interfere with Voiceover accessibility. For more details, you can refer to the following link:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/9702